# How to pass an argument to the external function in addEventListener

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener

OK this question already has a lot of answers in web, I have read all of them and I don't think any of them fit my situation. After tried like 2 hours I decide to give up and ask the people here:

**This is the simplified example:** I have a function, which will be triggered by a button click, I will call it click and it has an parameter with it. Inside the click function, I need to add an event listener to the window object use `addEventListener()`.

I need the event to be passed to the `handleKeydown()`, because I need to know if the shift key `(keycode == 16)` is pressed down and I need to pass the parameter `map` to the `handleKeydown()` because I need to do something on it. after that, there will be more things done, let's say it has a function to draw pictures on the map

**So I write the codes below:**

```
function click (map) { // can be called multiple times, so multiple listener are attached, not needed

    this.addEventListener("keydown", function(e) {handleKeydown(e, map)}, false)
    drawPictureOnMap(map);
}

function deletePictureOnMap() { 
    // user always call this function to delete the picture before they
    // call the click() to draw a new one

    // delete the picture on map
}

function handleKeydown(e, map) {
    if (e.keyCode == 16) {
        // do something to map, e. g.:
        // map.getLayers()
    }
}
```

**It works all fine until today, I find a big problem with it.**

Because the function click can be called multiple times, so I found that multiple event listener are attached to the window object. That has a negative effect on the performance.

The idea is to attach a `removeEventlistener()` to another function, which is mean to delete the picture on map. **Because, the user always delete the picture before they draw a new one.**

The Problem is, **I can't remove a event listener with anonymous function. But if I want to use external function, I can't find a way to pass the map parameter to it.**

Another Idea is, make the map parameter global, so I don't need to pass it to the handleKeydown. But I am not willing to do it.

Comment: Please update your question with a [mcve] demonstrating the problem, ideally a **runnable** one using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button; [here's how to do one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/)).

Comment: sorry, the real project is related with openlayers, the Minimal runnable demonstrating of the problem will cause like 300 lines. But the key point is only related with addEventListener and removeEventListener. So I can only show the issue this way. @T.J.Crowder

Comment: No, you **can** create an MCVE of just the `addEventListener`/`removeEventListener` aspect, sufficient to answer the question. You can choose not to, making it harder for people to help you. But you **can** do it.

Comment: I'm not sure if I completely understood your problem, still I want to suggest reading (hope it'll be helpful): https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2016/10/addeventlistener-once

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways to solve this. Without more information, the one that comes to mind is this: Maintain a `WeakMap` of the handlers for a given element (a `WeakMap` so that if the element is removed and all references to it are dropped, the map entry automatically gets removed). Even IE11 supports `WeakMap` (enough of it, anyway).

```
const elementClickHandlers = new WeakMap();
```

Within that element-to-handlers map, store a `Map` of the handlers keyed by `map`.

Then in `click`, use those maps:

```
function click (map) { // can be called multiple times, so multiple listener are attached, not needed
    let handlers = elementClickHandlers.get(this);
    if (!handlers) {
        handlers = new Map();
        elementClickHandlers.set(this, handlers);
    }
    let handler = handlers.get(map);
    if (!handler) {
        handler = function(e) {handleKeydown(e, map)};
        handlers.set(map, handler);
    }
    this.addEventListener("keydown", handler, false)
    drawPictureOnMap(map);
}
```

When removing, find the handler for the element and map and remove that:

```
const handlers = elementClickHandlers.get(theElement);
if (handlers) {
    const handler = handlers.get(map);
    if (handler) {
        handlers.delete(map);
        someElement.removeEventListener("click", handler, false);
    }
}
```

But there may be simpler ways to solve the problem we could suggest, if you showed a proper [MCVE](/help/mcve).